# Could not obtain information about Windows NT group / user, error code 0x3a

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, azure-active-directory, windows-server-2003, sqlclr

I am trying to deploy a SQLCLR library to SQL Server 2008 R2. In visual studio I have set up the data connection and it works correctly (I can run queries), but when I try to deploy I get the message "Error: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group / user , error code 0x3a."

This is strange because I have set up the data connection to use SQL server authentication on a different user name.

I receive the same error when I run CREATE ASSEMBLY while logged in to the SQL management studio with the different user name.

To add to the mystery, when I deploy using permission set SAFE everything is fine. However my assembly requires EXTERNAL ACCESS.

What could be the problem with deploying my assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue wasted so much time I feel compelled to share the solution so that nobody else falls into the same trap.

Issue was resolved by setting the SQL Server Active Directory Helper service to run on Manual, then rebooting the server.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arose in a different environment for me:

- Windows 10 box;
- The user Windows complained about was an AZUREAD user;
- On my Win10 box there was no SQL Server Active Directory
  Helper service, so I couldn't try the original solution posted by
  ose.

I was able to work round the issue by removing the AZUREAD user as a SQL Server user while I added the assembly.

In my case that user was not essential to have as a SQL Server user, but I dare say it would be possible to re-add the user back later should this be required.